# Change Brush Size Using UISlider

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-graphics

I am trying to use the UISlider to change the size of the brush for the iPad app school project that I am making but I can't figure out how.

I already have a UISlider connected to its outlet and action.

Here's my code for the brush size.

```
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), redAmt, greenAmt, blueAmt, alpha);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    touchDraw.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Setting line width is fine. Can you please show your code how you are drawing?

Comment: there you go Sir, i edited it. it's just a simple drawing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow you. Right now you're just setting the line width to `25.0f`. Why don't you set a variable to the value of the `UISlider` each time it changes, and set the line width to that?

Comment: It's better to do this than to ask the slider for the line width each time. Using views as the primary storage for your values is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0);
```

needs to be something like this:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.brushSizeSlider.value);
```

where `brushSizeSlider` is the name of the `IBOutlet` property wired to your brush size slider.

Comment: and of course you have to set the minimum and the maximum of that UISlider, too.

Comment: @rob just to make it clear sir, the IBOutlet not the IBAction? because XCode changed it "self->slider.value"

Comment: @Cristiano, Ok have a IBAction method which is to be called on changing the slider value. Get the value using sender object. Use that for drawing.

Comment: @Cristiano: You should put the `IBOutlet` macro on properties (as in `@property(weak) IBOutlet UISlider *brushSizeSlider;`), not instance variables. Then, among other advantages, you control whether you own (`strong`) or don't own (`weak`) the value of the outlet. The Resource Programming Guide gives guidance on what the ownership policy of an outlet should be.